# How do you set up Serilog to call a stored procedure in SQL Server when logging messages?

Tags: sql-server, serilog

How do you set up Serilog to call a stored procedure in SQL Server when logging messages?  I see how to use the [MS SQL Server sink](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/) to store messages directly in a database table, but I'd like to call a stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of any pre-built stored procedure sink for Serilog.

You can call the stored procedure yourself however by implementing the `ILogEventSink` interface:

```
class StoredProcedureSink : ILogEventSink
{
    public StoredProcedureSink(/* Connection info etc. */) { ... }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        // Invoke sproc using logEvent data
    }
}
```

These are plugged in at configuration-time:

```
var sink = new StoredProcedureSink(/* ... */);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Sink(sink)
    .CreateLogger();
```